Durrett Example 6.2.4 (Birkhoff's Ergodic theorem)
This example applies the Birkhoff's Ergodic theorem to prove the following result

if $X_0,X_1,\dots$ is an irreducible, positive recurrent Markov chain on a countable state space $S$. Let $\pi$ be its stationary distribution. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(X_m)\to \sum_{x\in S}f(x)\pi(x) \mbox{ a.s. and in } L^1
\end{eqnarray}
provided that $\sum_{x\in S}|f(x)|\pi(x)<+\infty$

I fail to see how we can directly apply the ergodic theorem here without assuming $X_0$ is in the stationary distribution $\pi$. Without this assumption, $X_0,X_1,\dots$ needs not to be stationary and hence cannot be ergodic.
Of course, as distribution of $X_m$ converges to stationary distribution $\pi$ in total variantion norm, the sequence in a sense $\textit{converges}$ to an ergodic sequence. But the ergodic theorem (theorem 6.2.1) proved doesn't deal with this case. Is there a generalization dealing with this?

Have a look: https://www.math.kth.se/matstat/gru/sf3953/Material/L8.pdf

@vanderWolf Thanks for the materials. It seems that the theorem 8.6 in your materials, if I understand it correctly, confirms my intuition that $X_0$ is in stationary distribution $\pi$ maybe necessary. In theorem 8.6, as it requires $Y\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_{\pi})$, then $Y\circ \theta^k(\omega)=Y(X_k(\omega))$ with $X_k$ is of stationary distribution $\pi$, am I right? But Durrett's conclusion holds for any initial distribution.

@vanderWolf Besides, I am slightly uncertain about the notation used in theorem 8.6, in writing $E_{\pi}[Y]$ it seems that $Y$ is treated as a r.v. defined on state space $(X,\mathcal{X})$. But it also states that $Y\in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}_{\pi})$, which says $Y$ is defined on the sequential canonical space.
